# Соединить данные из двух таблиц. JOIN. SQL

Tags: sql

По полю id_team вывести имя из таблицы `teams`. Нужно соединить два поля из одной таблицы с одним полем из другой. Дело в том, что тут есть поле id_team_one и id_team_two.

```
     select *,
    win * 3 as win_ace,
    draw * 1 as draw_ace
from(
    SELECT team_id, id_tournament, name_team_one, name_team_two,
           sum(win) AS win,
           sum(loss) AS loss,
           sum(draw) AS draw,
           sum(goals_s) AS goals_s,
           sum(goals_m) AS goals_m
    FROM
        (SELECT games.id_team_one as team_id, id_tournament,
        t1.name as name_team_one,
                IF(games.goals_one>games.goals_two,1,0) AS win,
                IF(games.goals_one<games.goals_two,1,0) AS loss,
                IF(games.goals_one=games.goals_two,1,0) AS draw,
                games.goals_one AS goals_s,
                games.goals_two AS goals_m
         FROM games
         WHERE games.`datetime` < NOW()
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT games.id_team_two, id_tournament,
         t2.name as name_team_two,
                          IF(games.goals_one<games.goals_two,1,0) AS win,
                          IF(games.goals_one>games.goals_two,1,0) AS loss,
                          IF(games.goals_one=games.goals_two,1,0) AS draw,
                          games.goals_two AS goals_s,
                          games.goals_one AS goals_m
         FROM games
         WHERE games.`datetime` < NOW() ) t
         join `tournaments` on id_tournament=tournaments.id
         join `teams` t1 on id_team_one=t1.id_team
         join `teams` t2 on id_team_two=t2.id_team
    GROUP BY team_id
) as foo
order by ((win * 3) + (draw * 1)) desc
```

Добавил join на таблицу teams. Выдает ошибку. #1054 - Unknown column 't1.name' in 'field list'

Comment: Я бы добавил поля типа `'ONE' AS team_name` и `'TWO' AS team_name` в запросы и учитывал бы его в группировке

Comment: 1) Где структура таблиц? 2) Если в одной таблице есть два поля-ссылки на вторую таблицу, то в источнике данных запроса нужно использовать 2 копии второй таблицы.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: *Выдает ошибку. #1054 - Unknown column 't1.name' in 'field list'* Правильно,  у тебя нет такой таблицы в этой точке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, сделал. Всем спасибо за помощь.

```
select *,
    win * 3 as win_ace,
    draw * 1 as draw_ace
from(
    SELECT team_id, id_tournament, team_name,
           sum(win) AS win,
           sum(loss) AS loss,
           sum(draw) AS draw,
           sum(goals_s) AS goals_s,
           sum(goals_m) AS goals_m
    FROM
        (SELECT games.id_team_one as team_id, id_tournament, t1.name as team_name,
                IF(games.goals_one>games.goals_two,1,0) AS win,
                IF(games.goals_one<games.goals_two,1,0) AS loss,
                IF(games.goals_one=games.goals_two,1,0) AS draw,
                games.goals_one AS goals_s,
                games.goals_two AS goals_m
         FROM games
         join `teams` t1 on id_team_one=t1.id_team
         WHERE games.`datetime` < NOW()
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT games.id_team_two, id_tournament, t2.name as team_name,
                          IF(games.goals_one<games.goals_two,1,0) AS win,
                          IF(games.goals_one>games.goals_two,1,0) AS loss,
                          IF(games.goals_one=games.goals_two,1,0) AS draw,
                          games.goals_two AS goals_s,
                          games.goals_one AS goals_m
         FROM games
         join `teams` t2 on id_team_two=t2.id_team
         WHERE games.`datetime` < NOW()) t
         join `tournaments` on id_tournament=tournaments.id
    GROUP BY team_id
) as foo
order by ((win * 3) + (draw * 1)) desc
```